# Can there be a require statement in the constructor in the solidity programming language please

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I actually think something is wrong with my constructor

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Application{

    uint public count;
    address public owner;
    address public constant ADDR = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;

    constructor(){
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getCount() public view returns(uint){
        return count;
    }

    function incCount() external {
        count++;
    }

    function deccount() public {
        count--;
    }

}
```

I was able to successfully compile but I'm cuurently unable to deploy. This is what the error that keeps coming on:

```
creation of Application errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When the code executes the constructor, the value of `owner` starts at `addr(0)`, so the `require` fails.

```js
    constructor(){
        require(owner == msg.sender);  // here owner=0x00
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
```

You can remove the `require` to let anyone deploy.